# LIKE operator is not case-sensitive in Filter query for shapefiles (QGIS 3.4)

Tags: qgis, query, filter

When I try to filter local shapefile with Query Builder (right-click on layer > Filter) using LIKE operator (which should be case-sensitive) it does not work properly. For example
query `"place_name" LIKE '%Wola'` returns both *Stara Wola* and *Starowola* (identically to ILIKE). 
I don't know why, but it works correctly when the same filter query is performed on the identical layer accessed via PostGIS.

Also: LIKE works good with local shapefiles in Open Attribute Table > Advanced Filter (but this is not the solution - one can only select rows using a query but not filter a layer). 
As we can read [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/16960), different behaviour between Query Builder and Attr. Table Advandced Filter comes from the fact that "one is handled by OGR, the other one by QgsExpression". If this is the case, then why does Query Builder work correctly on postgis layers?

I know this bug was reported several times (and even marked as 'wontfix'). Last time it was perhaps [4 years ago](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/21691) but nothing changed since then.

IU there any other way to filter shapefiles using SQL query?

Comment: You can use, virtual layer in Qgis, for filter shapefiles using sql query.

Comment: @JhonGalindo Thank you for your answer. This seems to work for LIKE, but now I get an error when trying with ILIKE:
`Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS SELECT *
FROM settlements
WHERE place_name ILIKE '%wola';: 1 - near "ILIKE": syntax error`

Comment: It is probably due to lack of ILIKE in SQLite...

Comment: You can try to use NOT LIKE, what do you think ?

Comment: Yes, I do this ("place_name" LIKE '%Wola' AND "place_name" NOT LIKE '%wola'), but let's say, it is irritating to do this every time. For my purposes the best solution for now is to create a postgis database, but for the participants of workshops on qgis basics for linguists and onomasticians (that I am preparing now) it is too much, I think ;) Thank you for your hints.

Comment: One more hint: use `glob('*Wola',"place_name")`. If SQLite is being applied, `glob` function is case sensitive.

Comment: The underlying database engine (dBase IV not SQLite) is not case sensitive, neither are personal geodatabases, PostgreSQL and file geodatabases are case sensitive; the SQL is passed directly to the database and the objects unique IDs then returned to form the selection. In short it's impossible to create a case sensitive query for shapefiles because the background parts aren't. If you want a case sensitive query use PostGIS or fGDB.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, are you sure that dbf engine is involved? There seems to be dbf.exe in the GRASS directory of my OSGeo4W installation but I do not think that QGIS is using that.

Comment: @user30184 it's in the OGR shapefile driver not as a package by itself. On windows there is an ODBC driver implementation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/dbase-driver-programming-considerations?view=sql-server-ver15 which might be why you can't see it in the expected folders. One of the earliest lessons I learned about accessing data sources is that the SQL is at the mercy of the the target database engine: time/datetime handling, functions, extended SQL, wild card and case sensitivity are all moderated by the database driver.

Comment: Should be somewhere here then https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/shape.

Comment: Read https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html `Starting with GDAL 3.1, LIKE is case sensitive, and ILIKE is case insensitive. In previous versions, LIKE was also case insensitive.` GDAL 3.1 is the current development version, release will come around May 2020. I suppose QGIS is using the same SQL machinery. I made a test with 3.1.0dev and LIKE is indeed case sensitive now against shapefile and other file based sources.